# admob interstitial Ads in sometime showing black screen

Tags: admob

Sometimes the interstitial ad is displayed right, but other times it is display a black screen
I don't understand what is the problem?

this my code:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this,
            getString(R.string.admob_app_id));

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.admob_interstitial));
    AdRequest adRequest1 = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest1);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
            super.onAdLoaded();

        }
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Do you get this in a published app? I have the same currently during development, quite regularly. I just [googled](https://www.google.com/search?q=admob+interstitial+black+screen&oq=admob+interstitial+black+screen&aqs=chrome..69i57.4999j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) it and it seems to be happening to lots of people without clear cause.

Comment: @August The error appears to occur if there is a slow internet connection or maybe the code is in a wrong place, so that it may interfere with other elements of the app
... yes my app is available on Google Play and i haven't encountered this black screen in a long time
(Other than that I received a policy violation and my ads visibility was greatly reduced :') )